# why is this quick sort not sorting

Tags: c, arrays, structure, quicksort

I have a hash table of structures. I wanted to sort the contents of the buckets using quick sort algorithm and here is the code i tried. The result hash table bucket content is not sorted at all.

```
#define BUCKETS 6000
#define BK_ENTRIES 1024
void q_sort(int,int,int);

typedef struct fpinfo
{
    char fing_print[33];
}fpinfo;
```

q_sort method

```
void q_sort(int left, int right,int bk)
{
    if(left>=right)
        return ;
    char l_hold[33], r_hold[33];
    int pivot=left;
    l_hold=hash_table[bk][left].fp;
    r_hold=hash_table[bk][right].fp;
    hash_table[bk][pivot].fp=hash_table[bk][left].fp;
    while (left < right)
    {
        while ((strcmp(hash_table[bk][right].fp,hash_table[bk][pivot].fp)>=0) && (left < right))
            right--;

        if (left != right)
        {
            hash_table[bk][left].fp=hash_table[bk][right].fp;
            left++;
        }
        while ((strcmp(hash_table[bk][left].fp,hash_table[bk][pivot].fp)<=0) && (left < right))
            right--;

        if (left != right)
        {
            hash_table[bk][right].fp= hash_table[bk][left].fp;
            left++;
        }

    }
    hash_table[bk][left].fp=hash_table[bk][pivot].fp;
    hash_table[bk][pivot].fp=hash_table[bk][left].fp;
    hash_table[bk][left].fp=l_hold;
    hash_table[bk][right].fp=r_hold;

    if ((strcmp(hash_table[bk][left].fp,hash_table[bk][pivot].fp)<=0))
        q_sort(left, pivot-1,bk);
    if ((strcmp(hash_table[bk][right].fp,hash_table[bk][pivot].fp)>0))
        q_sort(pivot+1, right,bk);
}
```

Here is how i called it in main

```
fread(hash_table,sizeof(hash_table),1,htfile);


for(int j=0;j<BUCKETS;++j)
{

    q_sort(0,BK_ENTRIES-1,j);
}
```

You might say the code is too long but i couldn't make it any shorter .

EDIT:

Here is the declaration of **hash_table**

```
struct fpinfo hash_table[BUCKETS][BK_ENTRIES];
```

I have solved my problem with the c library function qsort(). But in case any of you want to still look into this problem I have updated it as your suggestions.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger and printf().

Comment: @zvrba: I did use the debugger and have also inspected the output using printf. Still I couldn't identify the problem .

Comment: @John, can you tell us what the debugger output is?

Comment: It's long, it's complex and has too many stars and square brackets for most developers to just look at.  Like @zvrba says, you have to debug it.  Software development is 10% design and 90% debugging.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program.  Writing a pile of complex code and then asking the experienced developers here to do the heavy lifting of getting it working is er.. 'unfriendly'.  Hint - just supply it with a very small dataset that you can 'manually' track while running in the debugger.

Comment: 1) I am missing the definition for hash_table. 2) why all the casts? 3) what is the purpose of all the strcpy() calls (copying makes you guilty, because you'll have to remember to copy back sometimes)?

Comment: You modify `left` and `right` until they meet, then recursively copy `qsort` passing the new `left` and `right`. You need to pass the original `left` and `right` instead. Maybe there are other cases where you need to use the original values.

Comment: What's with all the ugly casts in the code? If the data is not a string of text, don't use string functions, you'd be better off using `memcpy` and `memcmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution. I just used the **qsort()** standard C function. I have included all of the source code so that all beginners like me can understand it better.

EDITED AS **wildplasser's** SUGGESTED:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

#define BUCKETS 6000
#define BK_ENTRIES 1024

int compare (const void * a, const void * b);
typedef struct fpinfo
{
    unsigned long long offset;
    unsigned long length;
     char fp[33];

}fpinfo;
struct fpinfo hash_table[BUCKETS][BK_ENTRIES];
void main()
{
    struct fpinfo e;
    char fname[100];
    printf("Enter source file name\n");
    scanf(fname);
    FILE *htfile,*f2;
    htfile=fopen(fname,"r+b");

    if (htfile != NULL)  
        { 
               fread(hash_table,sizeof(hash_table),1,htfile);
            for(int j=0;j<BUCKETS;++j)
            {
                qsort(hash_table[j],BK_ENTRIES,sizeof(e),compare);
            }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Couldn't open source file");
        exit(1);
    }
    f2=fopen("dest.txt","w+b");
    if (f2 != NULL)  
    {                           
        fwrite(hash_table,sizeof(hash_table),1,f2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Couldn't open  destination file");
        exit(1);
    }
            fclose(htfile); 

            fclose(f2);

}
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    struct fpinfo *fpa=(struct fpinfo*)a;
    struct fpinfo *fpb=(struct fpinfo*)b;
    return strcmp(( char*)fpa->fp,( char*)fpb->fp); 
}
```

Comment: BTW: you can copy structure objects literally in one swipe, like `e = hash_table[j][k];` (another way would be `memcpy( &e, &hash_table[j][k], sizeof e);`. BTW2: if you change the type of the .fp member from unsigned char[] to char[], you can omit all the ugly casts. BTW3: you use too many parentheses. BTW4: you are mixing C and C++ idioms.

Comment: The question is tagged C, but you are using a mix of C and C++ style I/O.

Comment: @wildplasser: you can't imagine how much i am learning from you guys. Thanks a million!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! Hint: read a lot of code. You could borrow some common constructs/idiom from it, and make life easier for yourself.

Comment: I love these "my solution is to just not write the code myself but reuse something which works already" solutions.